# Using Python urllib2, How can I stream between a GET and a POST?

Tags: python, streaming, urllib2

I want to write code to transfer a file from one site to another. This can be a large file, and I'd like to do it without creating a local temporary file.

I saw the trick of using mmap to upload a large file in Python: "HTTP Post a large file with streaming", but what I really need is a way to link up the response from the GET to creating the POST.

Anyone done this before?

Comment: By "large" you mean "too big to fit in memory", right? Because if we're just talking 200MB or something, the easy way to avoid creating a temporary file is to just `read()` into memory, never write it to a temporary file, and just send the string to the other request.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, or at least shouldn't.

`urllib2` request objects have no way to stream data into them on the fly, period. And in the other direction, response objects are file-like objects, so in theory you can `read(8192)` out of them instead of `read()`, but for most protocols—including HTTP—it will either often or always read the whole response into memory and serve your `read(8192)` calls out of its buffer, making it pointless. So, you have to intercept the request, steal the socket out of it, and deal with it manually, at which point `urllib2` is getting in your way more than it's helping.

`urllib2` makes some things easy, some things much harder than they should be, and some things next to impossible; when it isn't making things easy, stop using it.

---

One solution is to use a higher-level third-party library. For example, [`requests`](http://python-requests.org) gets you half-way there (it makes it very easy to stream from a response, but can only stream into a response in limited situations), and [`requests-toolbelt`](http://toolbelt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) gets you the rest of the way there (it adds various ways to stream-upload).

---

The other solution is to use a lower-level library. And here, you don't even have to leave the stdlib. [`httplib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html) forces you to think in terms of sending and receiving things bit by bit, but that's exactly what you want. On the get request, you can just call `connect` and `request`, and then call `read(8192)` repeatedly on the response object. On the post request, you call `connect`, `putrequest`, `putheader`, `endheaders`, then repeatedly `send` each buffer from the get request, then `getresponse` when you're done.

In fact, in Python 3.2+'s `http.client` (the equivalent of 2.x's `httplib`), `HTTPClient.request` doesn't have to be a string, it can be any iterable *or any file-like object with `read` and `fileno` methods*… which includes an response object. So, it's this simple:

```
import http.client

getconn = httplib.HTTPConnection('www.example.com')
getconn.request('GET', 'http://www.example.com/spam')
getresp = getconn.getresponse()

getconn = httplib.HTTPConnection('www.example.com')
getconn.request('POST', 'http://www.example.com/eggs', body=getresp)
getresp = getconn.getresponse()
```

… except, of course, that you probably want to craft appropriate headers (you can actually use `urllib.request`, the 3.x version of `urllib2`, to build a `Request` object and not send it…), and pull the host and port out of the URL with `urlparse` instead of hardcoding them, and you want to exhaust or at least check the response from the POST request, and so on. But this shows the hard part, and it's not hard.

Unfortunately, I don't think this works in 2.x.

---

Finally, if you're familiar with `libcurl`, there are at least three wrappers for it (including one that comes with the source distribution). I'm not sure whether to call `libcurl` higher-level or lower-level than `urllib2`, it's sort of on its own weird axis of complexity. :)

Comment: I guess I should start pushing for python 3... that really does look attractive.

Answer (score 0):

urllib2 may be too simple for this task. You might want to look into [pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/). I know it supports streaming.