# requests.get(, stream=True) with Python standard library

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, urllib

Per `ps aux`, it seems that `import requests` adds ~4mb of RAM to a  code I'm trying to optimize.

The usage of `requests` in the respective code is pretty basic, and I read that the  "regular" `requests.get` can be achieved via the standard library:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

urlopen("www.bla.com").read()
```

There is however a case where `verify=True, stream=True` is being used.

Can this also be somehow reasonably achieved via Python (3.8) standard library?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with your stream=True ? Show us how you are using requests and what you are doing so that an equivalent urllib usage can be provided

Comment: have you looked at this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24900110/15744300

Comment: Python allocates memory in larger blocks. I *highly doubt* that requests is to blame for all of the memory Python requested. If you want to measure memory allocations don’t look at the OS accounting information, use the `tracemalloc` module instead.

Comment: At any rate, `requests` is basically a friendly API wrapper around `urllib3`, which in turn is a much more powerful wrapper around `http.client`. If you really must strip back on libraries, look at each project’s source code and see what you can strip back to yourself. But make sure you use the right tools to decide on this, `ps aux` is not nearly fine-grained enough to say *anything* about library memory footprints.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for a linux target, there may also be the possibility of calling the [curl](https://curl.se/) binary. I once worked on a project where we used a python lib, but ended up calling a linux tool, which was a compiled C binary and for that reason notably more performant than any python code. I can't tell about the exact memory requirements of curl, but it may be an option. It is a quite sophisticated tool able to easily perform a huge range of REST requests.

GET example downloading a website:

```
curl -o savedpage.html http://www.example.com/
```

You can run it from python like so:

```
import subprocess
out = subprocess.check_output(["curl", "https://www.python.org/"])
print(out)
```

This may be an option, but deserves comprehensive consideration, since curl may not be pre-installed on the target machine. You could also deliver the curl binary with your code, but that requires the target not to change, because you would have to pre-compile the binary.

So it is not the most straight-forward solution, on the other hand it could be a simple solution.

Comment: Doesn't forking another process allocate more memory for that process too? Idk, but forking is not the first thing tool that comes to my mind when I'm optimising for memory.

Comment: I know it is uncommon and has its flaws to consider, but that is also why I added this long disclaimer and explanation. It is a valid option to consider.